# Disable Internet Explorer 8 Enhanced Security on Citrix

Tags: internet-explorer-8, citrix

We've recently upgraded Internet Explorer on our Citrix-servers (running Windows 2003) from version 7 to version 8.
Some users (it seems quite random) experience problems with specific sites (ex. Google Maps) after the upgrade. It doesn't load the website (the website itself is loaded but the map isn't) unless I add Google Maps as a trusted website.

I think it has something to do with the Enhanced Security-setting but this has already been uninstalled when using Internet Explorer 7.

Any other idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Apparently something went wrong with the user profiles after the upgrade of Internet Explorer.
Resetting the settings of the user in Internet Explorer (Tools >> Internet Options >> tab Advanced >> Reset Internet Explorer Setting) solved the problem.

Comment: Post your comment as an Answer, then accept it, this will not get you any reps, but will help others find the answer when searching the site.

Comment: @Moab I know but because I don't have enough reputation I still need to wait one hour before I can answer my own question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently something went wrong with the user profiles after the upgrade of Internet Explorer. Resetting the settings of the user in Internet Explorer:

1. Tools;
2. Internet Options;
3. Tab Advanced;
4. Reset Internet Explorer Setting.

This solved the problem.